# Search a folder with specific name in Scala

Tags: scala, io

There are many folders contains the daily build artifacts. I need to get the newest folder to test some parts inside. The name of the fold has the following style

```
xx.172-3
```

xx is a stable number and can be ignored. 172 is the 172th build chronologically. 3 is the 3rd version of 172. The length of the folder name is not consistent. There might have 34.99-0 before 34.120-11

A typical folders, under for example **/test** path, are

```
   /test |-/34.170-0/ 
         |-/34.171-0/  
         |-/34.171-1/ 
         |-/34.172-0/
         |-/34.171-1/ 
         |-/34.171-2/
         |-/34.171-3/
```

**Question:**

How can I find the latest build folder **/34.171-3** by using Scala?

**Note:**

I've thought about using the time stamp and it doesn't work. Because previous folder is free to access after build. The time stamp does not tell if it is the newest build

Comment: Is the filename length consistent or do you have things like `34.99-9` coming before `34.100-11`?

Comment: No, the length of the folder name is not consistent. yes I do have `34.99-9` coming before `34.100-11`. The only stable number is the 34.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use a Regex pattern to make sure the directory name is safe for comparison.

```
val dirPattern = raw"\d+.(\d+)-(\d+)".r

listOfDirNames.maxBy{
  dirPattern.unapplySeq(_)
            .collect{case List(a,b) => (a.toInt,b.toInt)}
            .getOrElse((0,0))
}
```

Comment: There might be an issue here.  method unapplySeq in class Regex is deprecated since 2.11.0

Comment: `unapplySeq(t:Any)` is marked for deprecation but _not_ `unapplySeq(s:CharSequence)`. I always compile with `-deprecation` and this code raised no warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a method which parses your file names into a tuple of 3 numbers:

```
import scala.util.Try

def parse(s: String) = s.split("[.-]") match { //simple one case thanks to jwvh ;)
   case Array(_, a, b) => Try(a.toInt, b.toInt).toOption //in case there's folder like 34.xxx-0
   case _ => None
}
```

And then just use it to find the last file:

```
 val lastFile = new File("/test")
    .listFiles(_.isDirectory)
    .maxBy(f => parse(f.getName))
```

In **Scala 2.13** you could also do:

```
def parse(s: String) = s match {
   case s"${_}.$a-$b" => Try(a.toInt, b.toInt).toOption
   case _ => None
}
```

which is arguably even more readable.